# How to add a new line from a for loop variable in a <td> cell

Tags: c#, html, css

I have the following line of code, that is creating a **"td"** Tag as it loop in my **foreach** clause.

```
 foreach (var documenttitle in title)
   {       
      _row += "<td valign=\"top\">" + documenttitle + "</td>";
   }
```

My problem is that I need to have a TD tag created at first but I don't want this td to repeat itself as it loop through my documenttitle. So all documenttitle should be in one TD.

Below is what I am getting and what I am expecting.

What I'm getting:
Table:
Column A ColumnB
DocumentTitle DocumentTitle (ALL in one line)

What I'm expecting:

DocumentTitle
DocumentTitle

Comment: You need to generate <tr> blocks as well in your foreach. Compare tr (table row) & td (table data).

Comment: Please edit your question and add in the resulting HTML code so we can see the code (not just the image how the HTML appears)

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is that I need to have a TD tag created at first but I don't want this td to repeat itself as it loop through my documenttitle. So all documenttitle should be in one TD

Jiggle the order of your code round to match what you're saying ..

```
_row +=  "<td valign=\"top\">";

foreach (var documenttitle in title)
{       
  _row += documenttitle;
} 

_row +=  "<td valign=\"top\">";
```